# How to escape or convert specific letter on thinking-sphinx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

for example when I search 'Désinfection' or 'hello(worlds)', Result = 0 because of 'é' and '('

I try to change it with '*' and spaces but no result

Sphinx  Unexpected search options: [:match_mode]
  Sphinx Query (1.2ms)  SELECT *, weight() as st FROM `form_core` WHERE MATCH('hello(worlds) @country 5') AND `active` = 1 AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 ORDER BY `store` DESC, `st` DESC LIMIT 0, 15 OPTION field_weights=(vip_keywords=20, categorie=7, keywords=4, rsu=3, rs=3, description=2), max_matches=150
  Sphinx  Found 0 results

Answer (score 0):

A few things to note here:

To have accented and non-accented characters treated as 'identical', you'll need to use the `charset_table` setting:

- https://freelancing-gods.com/thinking-sphinx/v4/advanced_config.html#character-sets-and-tables
- http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

It may be worth referring to someone else's value for that setting which covers perhaps all accented characters:

- https://yob.id.au/2008/05/08/thinking-sphinx-and-unicode.html

As for punctuation characters, they are not indexed by Sphinx in its default behaviour - so "hello(world)" in a field would actually be stored by Sphinx as "hello world". If you want punctuation indexed (which I would not recommend, because it'll make the field values far less flexible), you need to list those characters as part of your `charset_table` setting.

Also: I'm guessing you're using TS v3 or newer - which is great! - but that also means that `:match_mode` is no longer a useful option. TS v3+ uses Sphinx's SphinxQL query syntax (which you can see in your question - it's almost identical to SQL) - and queries there are always using what was previously defined as the extended match mode.

Comment: Thanks @pat for your reply , of course I remove all "e" character from charset_table and it's worked for me now I can search for example "déja vue". Thanks Pat for all your reply  best regards.